# How to automatically capitalize words when text swiping in Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

When customizing the display for the phone's virtual keyboard, how do you enable text swiping (shape writing) and have each word automatically capitalized?

This is for a C# XAML WinRT Windows Phone 8.1 app.

In the People app, you can enter a name, with words being automatically capitalized, and using text swiping at the same time.  So it is possible, but how?

Comment: Try the [`TextBox.IsTextPredictionEnabled`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox.istextpredictionenabled.aspx) and [`TextBox.IsSpellCheckEnabled`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox.isspellcheckenabled.aspx) properties.

Comment: @caffinatedmonkey  It works when using <TextBox InputScope="NameOrPhoneNumber" IsSpellCheckEnabled="True" IsTextPredictionEnabled="True"/>  You should add this as an answer.  And they should explain this better at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt280229.aspx

Comment: Yes the Microsoft documentation is trash unfortunately.

Comment: @caffinatedmonkey  The question was down voted.  I simplified and improved the actual question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [`TextBox.IsTextPredictionEnabled`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox.istextpredictionenabled.aspx) and [`TextBox.IsSpellCheckEnabled`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox.isspellcheckenabled.aspx) properties.

Comment: The thing is that these two properties are enabled by default, but that doesn't make it work...they have to explicitly typed in the XAML to work.  Doesn't really make a lot of sense actually.  And I'm still not sue why someone down voted my question.  It's definitely not some kind of obvious solution.  I think it's a handy feature and more developers should use it.

Comment: @theMaxx Read the remarks for `IsSpellCheckEnabled`. `Windows 8:  For Universal Windows 8 apps, the default is false.`

Comment: At the page https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br209688 (TextBox.IsSpellCheckEnabled property - Windows app development) it does say that, for universal windows 8 apps, but my question is clearly about windows phone 8.1.  That means that this would apply: "true if the TextBox input interacts with a spell check engine; otherwise, false. The default is true."

Comment: "Universal Windows 8 Apps" could mean all windows 8 apps OR it could be a typo for "Universal and Windows 8 Apps". I couldn't find anything about what a  "Universal Windows 8 App" is and I doubt anyone, even microsoft, knows what a "Universal Windows 8 App" is.